# can not add webpart to sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint

i create a website on my local machine but i can't add webpart to web page, it don't rise any error but th webpart don't display to the page. anyone help me.
Thanks

Comment: Is it an audienced web part? Do you have group permissions set on it? Is it a custom web part or a third-party (if third-party then I would ask their support).

Comment: Which SharePoint version and what browser do you use?

Comment: i use SharePoint 2007, firefox, IE, Chrom. but when i add webpart to the page it does not display and does not rise error

Comment: it a customer web part, i login with administrator user. and when i open "Solution manager" in Center administration it rise the error bellow:

"There are no solutions in the solution store. Before you can deploy a solution package, you must submit the solution package to the solution store in the configuration database by using the stsadm -o addsolution command"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it's ranking high in Google results, so I figured I'd answer it anyway.

Make sure you're not running any code in the layout page's codebehind that calls and then closes SPContext.Current.Web. I had this exact behavior and that was the culprit

To test, add a different web part to a default page layout. If it adds, then it's either your web part or your code behind. If you can't add any web parts to your custom layout, it's your code behind. If it's just your web part, it's your web part.

Remember, SPContext.Current.Web returns a reference to the current SPWeb object. SharePoint will close the object itself when it's done, and closing it early can cause "unpredictable behavior."

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Firefox some time ago, but the problem disappeared when we installed SP2 for SharePoint 2007. The only thing that surprises me is that you also have the problem with IE.